# What program generated output "Memory pressure relief"?

Tags: 16.04, ram

I am running two background jobs `eclipse` and `wine` in my terminal emulator `lxterminal`, when the terminal shows

```
Memory pressure relief: Total: res = 39469056/39215104/-253952, res+swap = 35393536/35139584/-253952
```

I was wondering what program generated the output?

Thanks.

Comment: https://linux-mm.org/Memory_pressure . Are you asking what program generates the message or why you are getting the message ?

Comment: The message itself is from the linux kernel - https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=memory%20pressure&fold_case=auto&regex=false&context=true